# Real time audio recording in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am building an application which needs to do real time audio recording. I am using Swift for the project - so unable to use Novocaine library (as it has some Obj-C++ code).

What I need is get small chunks of the audio recording (real-time) which I can process or send to my websocket. Is there a Swift library that I can use to achieve this?

In addition to getting the live audio from the microphone, I also need to show a real time waveform.

- Start recording
- Get an event every for few bytes of recorded data, where I can send these bytes to my websocket.
- Showing a waveform for the audio.

Let me know.

Comment: I tried however wasn't able to include the .h file because of the class keyword. Do you have a solution for this? The mentioned link doesn't present the solution for this.

Comment: I did check it out earlier. Can you point me to the exact example using AudioKit which does real time audio recording? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You do not need any of 3-rd party tools for getting audio from mic. It can be set up easily using AVAudioEngine. However, for minimising network traffic I suggest to use lame for compressing raw PCM audio stream into mp3.

[Here](https://github.com/vlider/Mic-recording-minimal-example) you can find project with minimal functionality for getting mic input and compressing into mp3. In this example project mp3 stores into Documents folder, so you can try and listen to make sure it works.

From this point you can take mp3 buffer and send via socket. You can also play with lame settings to change quality, etc.

There is another branch called `no-lame` where same functionality implemented without lame encoding. [Look here](https://github.com/vlider/Mic-recording-minimal-example/tree/no-lame)

Comment: I tried to run your code but ended up in a lot of errors. I tried with XCode 7.3 and XCode 8 both. Honestly, I am not looking for a compression mechanism for now - just looking at getting live audio from the mic. Could you please give me the snipped to do this?

Comment: That's weird, as I run this project using Xcode 8 without any problems. Please post exact errors you faced here, so we could investigate. Anyway, if you do not need compression - in separate branch you may find same project without compression part: https://github.com/vlider/Mic-recording-minimal-example/tree/no-lame

Comment: Thanks, I was finally able to get your branch no-lame working. I get a working wav file. However, when I convert the AVAudioPCMBuffer to NSData and send to my server using a socket connection - the server doesn't get a working wav file. What could be wrong here?

Comment: func toNSData(PCMBuffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) -> NSData {
        let channelCount = 1  // given PCMBuffer channel count is 1
        let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: PCMBuffer.floatChannelData, count: channelCount)
        let ch0Data = NSData(bytes: channels[0], length:Int(PCMBuffer.frameCapacity * PCMBuffer.format.streamDescription.memory.mBytesPerFrame))
        return ch0Data
    }

Comment: Thank you @ValeriiLider, your GitHub project helped me a lot. Just a note for anyone else using this, don't forget do call lame_close(lame) in the deinit method since it will otherwise cause memory leaks.

Comment: Hi @ValeriiLider, thanks a lot for your code sample, very helpful. I was wondering, is there any reason you went for the AVAudioEngine APIs (which are designed for audio manipulation, AFAICT), rather than with the AVCaptureAudioDataOutput suite of APIs? 
(I'm trying to get my head around which iOS API to use for this, and as usual, Apple doesn't make it easy to decide)

Comment: @julien_c, I just found AVAudioEngine API easy to setup and use than making it in old fashion way

Comment: @ValeriiLider your link is the only page where I found to write a buffer data into a AVAudioFile! Thanks!!

Comment: Does anyone know how to record stream audio through AVAudioEngine?